# Android: loopj is not importing

Tags: android, http-headers, httpclient, build.gradle

I am using android studio, when am trying to add dependency

```
 compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

and sync the project am getting an error

Error:Failed to find: com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9
Open File
Open in Project Structure dialog

when i open the **project structure -> Dependency** its showing under the library
 But the problem is that the library is not syncing.

when i try to clean the project am getting error like

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'Frendy'.
```

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/C:/Users/Binil/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/loopj/android/android-async-http/1.4.9/android-async-http-1.4.9.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/Binil/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/loopj/android/android-async-http/1.4.9/android-async-http-1.4.9.jar
>            file:/C:/Users/Binil/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/loopj/android/android-async-http/1.4.9/android-async-http-1.4.9.pom
>            file:/C:/Users/Binil/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/loopj/android/android-async-http/1.4.9/android-async-http-1.4.9.jar
>        Required by:
>            :Frendy:unspecified

Can any one please help me.

Comment: try after cleaning the project

Comment: please see the update question, after I clean the project am getting that error @Amy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add Maven Repositories it should work, its described at  https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http in gradle section

**this is example of my gradle :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
     maven {
        url 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/'
  }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mine.android"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'

}
}
```

Comment: i added the maven repositories ,tried both mavenCentral() and by using URL, mavenCentral() is not taking, then I try with the maven URL and add the loopj at that time am getting same error like the "loopj" is failed to find. after that i just clean  the project that time am getting file is not found as the question i mentioned @Mochamad Taufik Hidayat

Comment: can I look your gradle script?

Answer (score 0):

Just add below code in build.gradle 
                          `repositories {mavenCentral()maven {url"https://oss.onatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }  }`